# Show users last read posts for each user?

Tags: functions, shortcode, users

I'm trying to get logged in users most recently read 10 posts to show on their profile.

For example: user A's most recently read 10 posts
user B's most recently read 10 posts...

I tried creating this shortcode to do it, but it doesn't show me any result either error. How can I fix this?

```
function shortcode_recent (){
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 $post_id= get_the_ID();
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_readed_by', get_current_user_id() );
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'meta_key'         => 'post_readed_by',
    'meta_value'       => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );

    the_title();
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } 
    the_content();

endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
}

}
add_shortcode('post_recent',shortcode_recent );
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282438/how-to-get-and-display-logged-in-users-recently-read-posts/282453#282453).

Comment: Before I attempt a full answer: 1) why not adding "last_read_posts" like meta field to the user instead the post? and 2) setting this field while users are reading the post using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `update_post_meta` with `post_readed_by` meta key when a user visit each single post.

you can use `the_content` filter to update this with checking the `is_singular()`

Hope you know how to sort these